# On my Wordpress 5.4 website, how to remove all feeds? Including Category and Tags

Tags: plugins, rss, feed

Hi so I noticed on Google search console, that Google has indexed my new Wordpress v5.4 website's feeds as well.

Not only article feed, but also category and tags! I'm a wp newbie so can anyone please show me how to do this rss feed (for all sections/posts) via code into functions.php? I'm running a child theme btw.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing a lot of questions regarding removing feed URLs from Google - not sure why people want this done, however, here's a really comprehensive breakdown on how someone addressed this a few days ago.

The code in the question works for removing the feeds from the head and there's a link in the comments about redirecting feeds to 404 not found so Google stops indexing them.

[Remove all feeds from wordpress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/364884/remove-all-feeds-from-wordpress?noredirect=1#comment530911_364884)

Comment: Ok will try thanks!